# Recovering Pictures & Movies from Formatted Memory Card

Tags: data-recovery

I thought I've copied all of the pictures and videos that I've taken using my digital camera Canon Digital IXUS 860 IS to my computer. Then I format the memory card. Then I found I didn't take all of the files!

I don't have any other means of connecting the memory card to computer except via the camera. But the camera doesn't show it as a removable device directly in my computer so programs like Glary Utilities and PC Inspector didn't find the drive.

I didn't take any picture after I formatted it. Is there any free software that can help me to get the pictures and videos? My memory card is an 4 GB SDHC card.

Thanks.

Comment: after some searching im seeing that Canon IXUS maynot support Mass storage mode, from this [link](http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=686820) whr someone else has a very similar experience.. i guess USB card reader is your only choice..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva), or if that didn't work, [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec). Be careful you don't modify anything, though. (I recommend you **set the memory card's read-only protection switch** until you recover the data.)

Comment: *> Be careful you don't modify anything*; in other words, **make sure to set the recovery directory to somewhere else**.

Comment: neither recuva nor photorec recognizes the camera.

Comment: Then you need to go out and spend 10 or 20 bucks on a USB card reader to plug into your computer and read the card that way.

Answer (score 0):

If its the whole disk, testdisk may be able to restore it to as it was before it was reformatted - i've found that, where it works, its far more intuitive than photorec, and often has better results. I'd also suggest making a copy of the drive with some varient of dd before working on it.

Comment: testdisk didn't recognize the camera.